# Get how many groups have all values of column set as null?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table `@EmplTable` that has four rows. It's the name of four employees.

Then I have a table `@MonitorTable`, which monitors the work these employees do.

Assuming that nothing's havppened to the table, `@MonitorTable` will have 12 rows corresponding to the three weeks that these four employees will be working. Column `IsProcessed` is null for everything, which means nothing's been assigned.

Let's say `IsProcessed` is set to true for `EmpId` 3 of `WeekNum` 1, how can I determine how many groups of `WeekNum` have all four rows null? In this case, the result would be 2 (`WeekNum` 2 & 3), since `WeekNum` 1 has one row with `IsProcessed` set to true.

I'm including the script. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
declare @EmplTable table
(
    EmpId INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,   
    Name varchar(20)
)

insert into @EmplTable (Name) select 'John'
insert into @EmplTable (Name) select 'Mary'
insert into @EmplTable (Name) select 'Ron'
insert into @EmplTable (Name) select 'Bob'

declare @count int
select @count = count(*) from @EmplTable

declare @MonitorTable table
(
    EmpId int,
    WeekNum int,
    IsProcessed bit
)

insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 1, 1
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 2, 1
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 3, 1
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 4, 1
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 1, 2
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 2, 2
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 3, 2
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 4, 2
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 1, 3
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 2, 3
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 3, 3
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 4, 3

update @MonitorTable set IsProcessed = 1 where EmpId = 1 and WeekNum = 1

SELECT  WeekNum
FROM    @MonitorTable
GROUP BY WeekNum
HAVING  COUNT(CASE WHEN IsProcessed = 1 THEN 0
                   ELSE 1
              END) = @count

-- Should return 2, 3 since WeekNum has been updated. It returns 1, 2, 3.
```

Comment: Monitor table data is not matching with your isprocessed bit ,further could you post some example results with expected output

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But I've made a change to the query and the result I should get.

Comment: @rbhatup change `COUNT(CASE` to `SUM(CASE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should give you the 2 records you need

```
SELECT  WeekNum
FROM    @MonitorTable
GROUP BY WeekNum
HAVING  SUM(CASE WHEN IsProcessed = 1 THEN 0
                   ELSE 1
              END) = 4
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason I'm getting `WeekNum` 1, 2, 3 in the result. But I updated WeekNum 1, so it should only be 2 & 3. I've updated the script to show result.

Comment: @rbhatup had count first but changed to SUM instead

Comment: I was able to make it work with sum instead of count.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @EmplTable table
(
    EmpId INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,   
    Name varchar(20)
)

insert into @EmplTable (Name) select 'John'
insert into @EmplTable (Name) select 'Mary'
insert into @EmplTable (Name) select 'Ron'
insert into @EmplTable (Name) select 'Bob'

declare @MonitorTable table
(
    EmpId int,
    WeekNum int,
    IsProcessed bit
)

insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 1, 1
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 2, 1
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum, IsProcessed) select 3, 1, 1
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 4, 1
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 1, 2
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 2, 2
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 3, 2
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 4, 2
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 1, 3
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 2, 3
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 3, 3
insert into @MonitorTable (EmpId, WeekNum) select 4, 3

select * from @MonitorTable

if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null drop table #temp

select WeekNum as ct
into #temp
from  @MonitorTable
group by WeekNum
having sum(cast(isnull(IsProcessed,0) as int)) = 0


select count(ct) as ct from #temp
```